# apache cxf and wsdl in the classpath issue

Tags: jakarta-ee, cxf

I have created a service using the following command

```
wsdl2java -ant -impl -wsdlLocation classpath:wsdl/Interface.wsdl -server -d serverclasses Interface.wsdl
```

I created a folder res/wsdl and put the Interface.wsdl in there. I added the res folder to the build path.

However when I run the project it fails with this:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.ServerRtException: [failed to localize] cannot.load.wsdl(classpath:wsdl/Interface.wsdl)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.getPrimaryWsdl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.createEndpoint(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.publish(Unknown Source)
```

What is the issue here? What is the best way to handle this? Note I am using the command line to create the java classes from wsdl.

On a side note, one of the package names contains the keyword interface and hence will not compile. Is there a way to tell java to treat it not as keyword?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the issue here?

Seems the WSDL file is not in the classpath of the server. The classpath protocol is used when the wsdl file is inside the resulting jar file. It may not enough you put a res folder to the build path. The wsdl directory must be on the runtime classpath (or built inside the resulting jar).

When you start your server, you could (choose one of the options):

1. add a classpath parameter poiting to your res directory
2. use relative file path instead of your classpath protocol
3. when building the jar file, include the wsdl folder

> one of the package names contains the keyword interface and hence will
>   not compile

Indeed, the "Interface" is a reserved word and will be treated as a reserved word. You can force a custom package name or classname for the namespace or a service name.

Comment: How can you tell eclipse to include the wsdl folder in the jar file ? I prefer this option.

Comment: Assuming it's a simple java project (not maven or other automation-assisted built) you may try to simply copy the wsdl folder into your project source folder. The clean-build the project and check the jar file (though I haven't use Eclipse projects some time)

Comment: Seems like it is not because it can't find the wsdl file. As I made it an absolute path and it still couldn't find it. I read somewhere I needed to add the cxf-rt-frontend-jaws-3.1.7.jar file and it went past this error. Now I get a java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: Provider org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl could not be instantiated error. Maybe I am missing another jar file. What are the jar files required for a webservice?

Comment: Indeed you need the cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-<version>.jar + all its dependencies (a nice bunch of them). I suggest to use maven to build the project (and resolve all its dependencies) or download the whole cxf distribution